# How get link element with tag <a> from concrete column <td>?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm not very familiar with python and selenium library, so I have problems with apparently simple tasks. So, i know how to get all the links from a table:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector (". <table class> [href]")
```

But i don't need all the links, only those that meet a certain condition, so i organize the for loop and first find all the table rows:

```
rows = table.find_elements (By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
```

Each row in the table looks something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
     ...
    <td> <a href= "..."> </a> </td>
    <td> ... </td>
     ...
</tr>
```

If I find the appropriate column that way

```
href_data = row.find_elements (By.TAG_NAME, "td")[Nr]
```

and then try to get the link element with tag :

```
href_link = href_data.find_elements (By.TAG_NAME, "a")
```

then apparently an empty object is returned because of further output

```
print (href_link.get_attribute ("href"))
```

always produces an error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are only `a` elements in the rows are those who containing the `href`s,
after extracting rows

```
rows = table.find_elements (By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
```

you should directly extract href_links with

```
href_link = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
```

So now you can

```
print (href_link.get_attribute ("href"))
```

So the entire code should be:

```
rows = table.find_elements (By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
for row in rows:
    href_link = row.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
        print (href_link.get_attribute ("href"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've already tested this variant. I get printing errors again. Does it matter that I'm looking for the table like this:

table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('<table class>')?

Comment: 1) Are you trying to get the `href` attribute inside the for loop?  
2) Are all and each elements with `a` tag inside the rows are containing `href`s?

Comment: 1) Yes; 2) Only the first <tr> line does not contain an href, but i used try - except and i get an exception for all rows.

Comment: Try using `href_link = row.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")`  instead of `href_link = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "a")`

Comment: Unfortunately again only exceptions. The table is actually generated dynamically every time, can that be important? Strange that this search driver.find_elements_by_css_selector (". <Table class> [href]") works correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231879/discussion-between-prophet-and-melenkurion).